# java exec run python program, while python has no authority to I/O

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, cmd, exec

The following code has I/O authority in my local PC and runs correctly. However when I've tried to do this on my windows server2012, some problems occured. It can't run python code correctly by using exec, my python cannot give the final result. I think it has no authority to I/O, but why?

Java code:

```
package test;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class test {

        private static void generateFile() throws IOException{
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/test/input.txt", false));
            String eventString = "This is a example";
            bw.write(eventString);
            bw.close();
        }

        private static void getFile() throws IOException{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/test/output.txt"));
            String jsonResults = br.readLine();
            br.close();

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            generateFile();

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec("python test.py", null, new File("src/test/"));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));  
            String line;  
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                System.out.println(line);  
            }  
            in.close();  
            try {
                pr.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                pr.destroy();
            }

            getFile();
        }

    }
```

python code:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
line  = f.readline()
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(line)

print("Done!")
```

ERROR infomation :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\test\output.txt (The system cannot find the specified file.)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at test.test.getFile(test.java:21)
    at test.test.main(test.java:49)
```

Answer (score 0):

Various things here (for the moment more "code quality" hints):

- Your poor method is doing **way too many** things. Example:

Individual "parts", like the following - should all go into a simple helper methods:

```
String eventString = getJsonEventListInTopic(topicLabel);
FileWriter fw = ...
fw.close();
```

- Meaning: you want to read about the [Single Layer Of Abstraction principle](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction)
- The **core** point to make progress on your actual question: when you **run** your python script manually on that windows system (with exactly the same arguments/parameters) on the command line - does that work? You know, it could be something super-simple as "python.exe is not in your path"

Comment: Firstly, thx for your kindly advice.  I will read it respectively. Then, I've tried this code both on eclipse and run python script with cmd alone with my PC

Comment: Whats more, I've also tried this script with cmd on server and it worked.

Comment: Then you want to add all error information like stack traces to your question.

Comment: I've add error info. lines before "congrat" imply python code run correctly. But when continue runnning java code,result file  is mentioned not exists.

Comment: Also,it not exists in the directory indeed

Comment: Is your problem resolved then? The python script is not creating that file?

Comment: Not yet. So it troubled me a lot. I doubled maybe it need super authority. But few questions mentioned it.

Comment: Well, it is hard to help with such input. You probably want to step back and look into creating an [mcve] for us. In any case; you are posting only parts of that method, and we have no idea where the line numbers from the exception stack trace are pointing to. In other words: given your current input, there is nothing we could do to help.

Comment: OK. I'll write an example and do some test. Could you give me your email?

Comment: Sorry, but no. This is not a service where you find people that hold your hand while you are debugging your problem. Please read my last comment again; it contains **clear** instructions regarding the input that you should provide here in order to maybe find people that can help.